# C/C++: Are IEEE 754 float addition/multiplication/... and int-to-float conversion standardized?

Tags: c++, c, ieee-754

Example:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float f1 = 1;
    float f2 = 4.f * 3.f;
    float f3 = 1.f / 1024.f;
    float f4 = 3.f - 2.f;
    printf("%a\n",f1);
    printf("%a\n",f2);
    printf("%a\n",f3);
    printf("%a\n",f4);
    return 0;
}
```

Output on gcc/clang as expected:

```
0x1p+0
0x1.8p+3
0x1p-10
0x1p+0
```

As one can see, the results look "reasonable". However, there are probably multiple different ways
to display these numbers. Or to display numbers very close.

Is it guaranteed in C and in C++ that IEEE 754 floating arithmetic like addition, multiplication and int-to-float conversion yield the same results, on all machines and with all compilers (i.e. that the resulting floats are all bit-wise equal)?

Comment: You seem to be asking multiple things here: Whether the int-to-float conversion is uniquely specified, whether the arithmetic is uniquely specified and whether the output representation is uniquely specified. These seem like three independent questions to me.

Comment: @user17732522 What's the different between "output representation uniquely defined" and "arithmetic uniquely defined"? If arithmetic is not unique, then the representation can not be unique? And if representation is not unique, since there is no result without a representation, then the arithmetic can't be unique?

Comment: But to clarify, I just want to ask, if I do this on two machines with 2 compilers and do a memcmp of both results, will this always lead to "equal memory"?

Comment: `memcmp` will be a fourth question. Just because the value of the variables is equal doesn't generally mean that `memcmp` will compare them equal. And the text representation from `printf` being equal definitively doesn't imply that the value of the variables is equal or that `memcmp` will compare them equal.

Comment: The text representation produced by `printf` may or may not be exactly specified for any given value of the variable. That would be independent of whether arithmetic can produce different results (e.g. due to rounding differences).

Comment: I think you should clarify in the question that your last comment is the main point you want to ask about.

Comment: Thanks. I added if the results would be bitwise equal on all machines.

Comment: floating point numbers are subject to endianness just like ints are. So the raw memory representation is not the same from machine to machine, maybe relevant to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unless the macro `__STD_IEC_559__` is defined.

Basically the standard does not require IEEE 754 compatible floating point, so most compilers will use whatever floating point support the hardware provides.  If the hardware provides IEEE compatible floating point, most compilers for that target will use it and predefine the `__STD_IEC_559__` macro.

If the macro is defined, then IEEE 754 guarantees the bit representation (but not the byte order) of `float` and `double` as 32-bit and 64-bit IEEE 754.  This in turn guarantees bit-exact representation of `double` arithmetic (but note that the C standard allows `float` arithmetic to happen at either 32 bit or 64 bit precision).

The C standard requires that float to int conversion be the same as the `trunc` function if the result is in range for the resulting type, but unfortunately IEEE doesn't actually define the behavior of functions, just of basic arithmetic.  The C spec also allows the compiler reorder operations in violation of IEEE754 (which might affect precision), but most that support IEEE754 will not do that wihout a command line option.

Anecdotal evidence also suggest that some compilers do not define the macro even though they should while other compilers define it when they should not (do not follow all the requirements of IEEE 754 strictly).  These cases should probably be considered compiler bugs.

Comment: Re “the C standard allows float arithmetic to happen at either 32 bit or 64 bit precision”: The C standard allows floating-point precision to happen at any precision at or better than the nominal type.

Comment: Re “IEEE doesn't actually define the behavior of functions, just of basic arithmetic”: IEEE-754 specifies the square root operation and conversions between binary and decimal and recommends behaviors for various mathematical functions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Not if `__STD_IEC_559__` is defined -- that's one of the things it is supposed to imply

Comment: As far as I know, IEEE 754 does not specify the exact result of the arithmetic operations.

Comment: Re “that's one of the things it is supposed to imply”: Where does it say that?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: IEEE-754 does specify the exact numerical results of the arithmetic operations.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: which version ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: All of them.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: can you pinpoint where in 754-2008 ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: IEEE 754-1985 4.3: “… Except where stated otherwise, every operation shall be performed as if it first produced an intermediate result correct to infinite precision and with unbounded range, and then rounded that result according to one of the attributes in this clause…”

Comment: "C standard allows float arithmetic to happen at either 32 bit or 64 bit precision" --> With `FLT_EVAL_METHOD == 2`, it may happen at `long double`.

Comment: @ChrisDodd "If the hardware provides IEEE compatible floating point, most compilers for that target will use it and predefine the `__STD_IEC_559__` macro.".  Adherence and proof of `__STD_IEC_559__` is quite challenging even with compliant HW such that many compiler do not bother setting it that seemingly could.    Do you have some have evidence to support the "if  ....most" claim - to avoid [Hitchens razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitchens%27s_razor) ?  The "do not define the macro even though they should while other compilers define it" obliges 100% compliance, not just close.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it guaranteed in C and in C++ that IEEE 754 floating arithmetic like addition, multiplication and int-to-float conversion yield the same results, on all machines and with all compilers (i.e. that the resulting floats are all bit-wise equal)?

**No**

---

If the exceptional compiler defines `_STDC_IEC_559__`, then **almost yes**.

> An implementation that defines **STDC_IEC_559** shall conform to the specifications in this annex.
> C17dr Annex F (normative) IEC 60559 floating-point arithmetic

IEEE 754 floating arithmetic like addition, multiplication and int-to-float conversion yield like results when `_FLT_EVAL_METHOD_ == 0`.  When `_FLT_EVAL_METHOD_ > 0`, wider floating point math may be used for many operations causing different results.  Yet even with `_FLT_EVAL_METHOD_ == 0`, I have doubts that *all* FP code will compute with exactly the same result.

For highly portable FP code, a variation tolerance should be expected.

---

OP is also looking for bit-wise equivalent.  FP has endian issues too, so 2 implementations could meet all IEEE 754 criteria, yet differ in endian.

Answer (score 0):

Realize that both the C and C++ standards strive to be inclusive of unusual architectures.  They would never mandate strict adherence to IEEE-754.

Also realize that the systems that do use IEEE-754 will rely on the processor architecture to implement it correctly.  Your actual question then is how well do the processors conform to the IEEE-754 rules, which is hard to answer with authority.  The [Intel Pentium famously had a bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_FDIV_bug) that produced wrong results for a tiny subset of operations.

I don't know if the conversion of integers to float is as tightly specified as other operations, but I suspect it is.  A 32-bit IEEE-754 float has 24 bits of mantissa, and can therefore hold any 24-bit integer without loss of precision.  That would be the range from -16777216 to 16777216.  I would be very disappointed in any implementation that couldn't perform the operation 100% reliably.  Outside of that range there are integer float values that can't be represented, so rounding should be applied to determine the final value.  For example there are no valid floats between 2147483520 and 2147483648, so what should happen if you try to convert 2147483583 or 2147483585?  I honestly don't know what the result will be, or whether that result would be correct.